# responseText contains extra whitespace characters (new lines, line feeds), how to prevent and remove them?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, responsetext

I have an ajax script that calls a php file.

The php file echos "yes" or "no", I want to use the strings to do logical comparisons.

In the javascript, I want to compare the string in the responseText to see if it is == to "yes" (or "no").  But the comparison fails.

So I do the alert responseText, and it does show "yes" (or "no") as the string.  But I read on here that the responseText might contain hidden whitespace characters, so I did the string length of responseText and it shows that the string length is 4 characters longer than what it should be.  So I escaped the responseText alert(escape(responseText)) and it shows that I have %0A and %0D (newlines and line feeds) hidden at the end of the responseText string.

I read that these characters are added on by php, but I also read that the extra characters are different among different php versions/servers.

How to prevent these extra whitespaces without using regex, since regex might remove intentional whitespaces?

Please don't suggest using jquery or mootools as answers.

TIA

Comment: You can write a regex to remove only newlines and/or linefeeds, while ignoring other forms of whitespace. `/\r?\n?$/` should do that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I read that these characters are added on by php, but I also read that the extra characters are different among different php versions/servers.

That's wrong. That's simple to verify: create a test.php file, write this and only this: `<?php echo "test";` (without `?>`) into it and execute it. There will be no whitespace.

These whitespaces most probably come from your scripts. A common error is to leave some trailing newlines after a closing php tags (`?>`), which results in a new line being printed.

Verify that all files included before or after you do `echo "yes";` don't echo anything and don't have a trailing newline after a `?>`.

The easiest way to avoid this problem is do not use php close tags at end of files (they are not mandatory).

Comment: Thank you arnaud, this is the explanation that I was looking for to explain the appearance of the extra characters.  It works, and I just need to keep this in mind about not have extra carriage returns in the php files.  I did not know that the closing tag is not required, good to know.

Answer (score 1):

I know you asked about doing the comparison without regexes, but given the conditions you mentioned above, that's going to be a very quick and effective way to get your answer, and won't necessarily perturb any other processing.

```
var trimmedResponse = responseText.replace(/^\s*/,'').replace(/\s*$/,'').toLowerCase();
if (trimmedResponse == 'yes') {
  // do your 'yes' case
} else if (trimmedResponse == 'no') {
  // do your 'no' case
} else {
  // do your 'none of the above' case
}
```

That's going to trim off leading white space, trailing white space (including the CR/LF combo), and convert to lower case just for comparison.

Comment: doesn't fixes the root of the problem ;)

Comment: thanks Ken, this function will come in handy.  Arnaud precisely explained the cause of the problem.  I will use your function just in case I have extra white spaces in my php files.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be going at it the wrong way. Instead of manually trying to create a response why don´t you use PHP arrays as a data structure and JSON for delivery?

```
<?php
$flag = false
if (condition){
  $flag = true;
}

$arr = array("is_true" => $flag)
$json = json_encode($arr);

// See http://www.geekality.net/2010/06/27/php-how-to-easily-provide-json-and-jsonp/
// Set JSONP header
header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');

// Get callback from $_GET and prepend the JSON data
echo isset($_GET['callback'])
    ? "{$_GET['callback']}($json)"
    : $json;
```

Comment: thanks for taking the time, but I don't need json for my purpose

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using PHP's [trim()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) function before sending the data?

Comment: This would remove intentional spaces, and this doesn't fixes the root of the problem ;)

Comment: Trim() only removes whitespace from the start/end of a string - not actual spaces between words.

Comment: There may be intentional spaces at the begining or end of the response ;) (OP asked not to remove them)

Comment: He didn't specifically say there would be intentional spaces at the start/end, only that he didn't want to remove intentional spaces.

Comment: Thanks Ashley, php trim does not fix the problem in this case. The extra whitespaces are added during the data transmission back to the javascript, see arnaud's explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Even if it's possible to look after all PHP script to avoid CRLF before or after php tag, this is not a good option as you can imagine adding in a few days, or month or years (without wanting!) a CRLF in a file and this will impact another part of your web site.

In fact, to avoid this problem you have two options:

**Option 1**: Let php send the data so with the garbage at beginning, and clean the data in Javascrpt with:

```
 response = http.responseText;
 response = response.replace(/[\n\r]+/g, '');
```

In this case this means you clean ALL the CRLF (change the Regex to clean only at beginning if needed or to clean also spaces)

**Option 2** (better I think) is to clean the output buffer of PHP immediatly before sending the data to browser. So:

```
 ... many code here
 ob_end_clean();
 echo $data_for_the_browser;
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I solved this problem by removing spaces between two php blocks in same php file ( "***...`? >  < ?php`...***" ) which it requires by *require_once()* method.

```
<?php 
  //your code
?>
*this space might appear in the XHTTP responce*
<?php 
  //your code
?>
```

--OR--
you can send your data as JSON Object from the server script (php) , for this you can use `json_encode()` . for the client side (javascript) you may use `eval(this.responce)` .