# check ajax callback is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
        $http({
            url: "php/add.php",
            method: "POST",
            data: {
                'uId': this.uId,
            },
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            }
        }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {

            if (data == "") {}else {
                alert('not empty');

            }

        });
```

I check my network tab in chrome's console, nothing has been echo, but the alert still pop up. Why?

Comment: print data in alert to know what exactly coming after ajax

Comment: You might have non-printable characters or whitespaces in the response. What does `data.length` tell you?

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar: If the string contains white spaces then an alert wouldn't really help either.

Comment: try `if ($.isEmptyObject(data))`

Comment: @John: I don't see a reason why `data` would be an object. Does `$.isEmptyObject` work for strings too (which would be surprising tbh)?

Comment: Its for Objects. The questions says that in alert he gets nothing. Lets see what it returns. I've used json responce and always comes as object...so

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7209846/responsetext-contains-extra-whitespace-characters-new-lines-line-feeds-how-t

Comment: thanks @rajeshkakawat, trim work!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/65DqC/ ?