# responseText contains extra whitespace characters (new lines, line feeds), how to prevent and remove them in jsp?

Tags: ajax, jsp

[responseText contains extra whitespace characters (new lines, line feeds), how to prevent and remove them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7209846/responsetext-contains-extra-whitespace-characters-new-lines-line-feeds-how-t)

Please Read above link

My jsp page send **" okay"** or **" not"** including whitespace.
How to prevent and remove whitespace or newlines

**valid.js**

```
window.onload=initPage;
function initPage(){
    alert("Browser Started");
    //call checkUsername function
     document.getElementById("username").onblur=checkUsername;
 }
function checkUsername(){
    request=createRequest();
    if(request==null){
        alert("Unable to create request");
    }else{
        alert("Request Object Created")
         var theName = document.getElementById("username").value;
         var username = escape(theName);
         //create url pass username
         var url= "checkName.jsp?username=" + username;
         //any change execute showUsernameStatus function
         request.onreadystatechange = showUsernameStatus;
         request.open("GET", url, true);
         request.send(null);
    }
}
function showUsernameStatus(){
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
        if (request.status == 200) {
            var val=request.responseText;
            alert("Response: "+val);
             if (val == "okay") {
                    //something
                  } else {
                    //something
                  }
        }
    }
}
```

**checkName.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%String username=request.getParameter("username");
    System.out.println("Username:"+username);
    if(!username.equals("") && username!=null){
        if(!username.equals("Raju")){
            out.print("okay");
            System.out.println("okay");
        }else{
            out.println("not");
            System.out.println("not");
        }
    }
%>
```

Comment: Post your code here without code hard to figure out your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [trim()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_trim_string.asp) in Javascript function:

```
var val=request.responseText;   
if (val.trim() == "okay") {
    // something
} else {
    // something
}
```

Or you can use [trimDirectiveWhitespaces=true](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19316-01/819-3669/bnajm/index.html) in jsp page

```
<%@ page trimDirectiveWhitespaces="true" %>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, i encourage you to use JSON Object for these kind of work.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9046331/creating-a-json-object-in-jsp-and-using-it-with-jquery) is a good example how to use JSON in your JSP page.

Now in your case, you must note that, to trim the results that you took from JSP page.

You must use trim in JavaScript function.

```
 if (val.trim() == "okay") {
     //something
 } else {
     //something
 }
```

or you can use regex to remove all white spaces:

```
var newVal = val.replace(/\s+/, "");
```